# Suppress certain content types from taxonomy term list display (D6)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm trying to suppress certain content types (blogs) from displaying in the taxonomy term list. (taxonomy/term/*)

I realize that a specific content type can be turned off for a vocabulary but we have hundreds of nodes that have tags defined.

Answer (score 2):

use a view for taxonomy/term/* (it is created by default, you just need to enable it) and set a filter for it to exclude the blog_post node types